# Python Split string by comma unless proceeded by a space

Tags: python, string, csv

I have a long string which I need to separate into a list by commas, however when the comma is followed by a space, I do not want it to be separated. e.g:

string:

```
str = 'foo,bar,hello, you'
```

desired list:

```
des_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello, you']
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re` module:

```
import re

txt = 'foo,bar,hello, you'

print( re.split(r',(?=[^\s]+)', txt) )
```

Prints:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'hello, you']
```

Answer (score 0):

use "split()" function:

```
str = 'foo,bar,hello, you'
des_list = str.split(',')
#des_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'hello, you']
```

Comment: This doesn't give what OP wanted, your code gives output as `['foo', 'bar', 'hello', ' you']`